# Regex to highlight Strings in code

Tags: regex

I'm developing a small code editor and I would like to match Strings so I can highlight them a different color.

Example:

```
myvar = array('VOLVO', 'TOYOTA')
```

Using regex expression \'.*\' I get one match 'VOLVO', 'TOYOTA'

However, what I want are two matches: 'VOLVO' and 'TOYOTA'

Is this possible to achieve with a single regex expression?

Comment: Please tag your question with the relevant programming language (e.h PHP, ...). In your example the quotes are not part of the string. Further, do you want to match only one of them ? which one ? the question is not clear to me.

Comment: If you know which strings you want to highlight, why do you need regex at all ?

Answer (score 0):

Someone did suggest the following expression:

\'[^\']*\'

Which in fact solves my problem: I get two matches, one for 'VOLVO' and one for 'TOYOTA'.